# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function at index.html:25:18

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, promise

```js
try {
  async function getPlanets() {
    let response = await fetch('https://swapi.py4e.com/api/planets/');
    let data = await response.json()
    return data;

  }
} catch (error) {
  error = console.log(error);
}
getPlanets().then(data => {
  data.forEach(planet => {
    const markup = `<li>${planet.name}</li>`;
    document.querySelector('ul').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
  });
});
```

the above code is throwing the error shown in the title, ive done some googling and I honestly just think ive been staring at this too long and need a second opinion, any thoughts on why it would do this? I kind of think its because the swapi is not returning an array so forEach isnt allowed, but if thats the case how do i get it to grab the array? because it is there i saw it in the console earlier its an array with 10 planets in it however its property is called "result" is this where I went wrong?

apologies if this was a bad question I am still new to this stuff and practical exercises seem to help BUT I BE STUCK ATM!

I tried looking through documentation, however I was following a short video on making an API call and then displaying that info to your webpage, but then it threw the error and at this point I feel like I'm just thinking about it the wrong way and its a simple fix.

I think it has something to do with the response being an object and not an array but again if that's the case how do I grab the "result:" array so I can loop through it and display the planet name that's the question at the very top

Comment: If it's not an array, why are you trying to loop over it? It may just be a single object, so you can use `data.name`. Please show the output of `console.log(data)`

Comment: As you suspected, `data` is an object and not an array, which leads to your error.
The data you want lies inside the `results` property of `data`. So, you can try to access that property. To read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: `data.results.forEach(...)`

Comment: You should look at the data [you're receiving](https://swapi.py4e.com/api/planets/?format=json) (which you can do in your dev tools network tab). It's an object with `count`, `next`, `previous`, and `results` properties. `results` is the array you want to iterate over.